# using datenum results in not showing both strings

Tags: matlab

**1. How do I read in this data properly so that the date parses properly?**
I am trying to concatenate strings I read from a file but the output I get is mixed up.
The output is the x axis.Also, the spacing from x axis has numbers instead of the string I want.
The file has 4 columns,date,time,temperature and value.
The date is "01.01.2013 " and the time "09:08:02"

Also, if I want to use only first column (with date) how can I do this?
Because using datenum(mydata{1}) results to "Cannot parse date 01.01.2013"

```
...
mydata = textscan(fid, '%s %s %f %f', 'delimiter',';', 'HeaderLines',1);
date={};
temp={};
..
date{1}=datenum( strcat(mydata{1},{' '},mydata{2}) );
...
```

**2. How do I correct the axis ticks?**

I am then trying to plot data using plotyy and want the x-axis to be the date, but I am getting two different axis labels.

Here is the code I am using:

```
temp = mydata{4};
plotyy(date,temp,date,2*temp);
datetick('x','mmm.dd,yyyy');
```

Here is the resulting image:

[image]

---------------UPDATE---------------------------------------

Here is the code:

```
fid = fopen('test2.txt','r');
mydata = textscan(fid, '%s %s %f %f', 'delimiter',';', 'HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fid);

date=datenum( strcat(mydata{1},{' '},mydata{2}),'mmm.dd,yyyy HH:MM:SS' );
temperature=mydata{3};
value=mydata{4};


[AX,H1,H2]=plotyy(date,temperature,date,value,'plot'); 
set(get(AX(1),'Ylabel'),'String','Temperatures');
set(get(AX(2),'Ylabel'),'String','Value');



set(H1,'LineStyle','--');
set(H2,'LineStyle',':');
datetick(AX(1),'x','mmm.dd,yyyy');


title('Temperatures - Values');
xlabel('Date')
```

and the file

```
Date;Time;Temp;value
Jan.01,2013; 11:00:00;20;10                         
Feb.08,2013; 12:00:00;23;11
Mar.04,2013; 04:02:00;24;15
Apr.10,2013; 08:04:00;28;20
May.10,2013; 12:05:00;32;30
Jun.04,2013; 10:06:0;33;27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Parsing input**

You are receiving the "cannot parse" error, because you are also not including a format string (formatIn). See the documentation for [datenum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html).

If you want to convert only the first column to the date, this would look like:

```
date=datenum(mydata{1},'mm.dd.yyyy');
```

If you want to convert both the first and second columns, try:

```
 date=datenum( strcat(mydata{1},{' '},mydata{2}),'mm.dd.yyyy HH:MM:SS');
```

Here is the entire code I am running, which seems to work. Note that there is no header row in my datafile.

```
% data.txt
% 01.01,2013; 11:00:47;10;20
% 01.02,2013; 11:00:57;10;40

fid = fopen('data.txt');
mydata = textscan(fid, '%s %s %f %f', 'delimiter',';');
date=datenum( strcat(mydata{1},{' '},mydata{2}),'mm.dd,yyyy HH:MM:SS');
```

**2. Getting correct plots**

There are two different x-ticks for plotyy command. By setting datetick in the way you did, you are only changing one of them. Instead, change first x-tick to date tick and set the second x-ticks to empty.

```
temp = mydata{4};
[AX,H1,H2] = plotyy(date,temp,date,2*temp);
datetick(AX(1),'x','mmm.dd,yyyy');
set(AX(2),'XTick',[])
```

Comment: :It gives me " Failed on converting date string to date number.".I use "01.01,2013; 11:00:47;10;20       
" and datenum( strcat(mydata{1},{' '},mydata{2}),'mmm.dd,yyyy HH:MM:SS' );

Comment: :I am taking the figure i uploaded..It messes with x axis values.

Comment: :If I use 'XTick'command it goves me "Invalid property found." and it removes all the ticks from y axis and even the title.And in x axis it appears a number '7.353' .I want in the x axis to appear 'Jan.01,2013  11:00:00'.

Comment: @George, please provide more information about your plotting. I achieve the desired effect with my code, but I am not sure exactly how you are calling your plot functions.

Comment: :I updated.I want in x axis to see the date and time "Jan 01,2013 11:00:00'.Thanks!

Comment: :Ok , it did it!Just , I want to show both date and time.It shows only date now.If I do "datetick(AX(1),'x','mmm.dd,yyyy HH:MM:SS');" it shows 00:00 as time.

Comment: Can't figure it out. I recommend just setting XTick and XTickLabel with set command instead of date tick: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15HXQ/

Comment: :I think I found it!Use date1=datenum( strcat(data{1},{' '},data{2}),'mmm.dd,yyyy HH:MM:SS' ); and then 
date=datestr(date1,'mmm.dd,yyyy HH:MM:SS');.In plot use date1 and in set(AX(1),'XTickLabel',date);.The only problem is the spacing I think.The date comes on the time but anyway.Thank you very much for your help.